# Suitable platform supported by ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it can be seen in the figure below, I need a Robotic platform that can move this stage along X and Y in at least 50mm range and rotate it around Z axis in a range of +-10 degrees. A camera is going to be positioned under this stage to track the motion. Lowest possible height for the stage would be 500mm+ 100mm (for camera and its fixture). A precision of 0.02 mm is needed for the motion.
It would be great if anyone can suggest me about the simplest available platform supported by ROS that can be used for this purpose.

Thank you,
Nima

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67572/suitable-platform-supported-by-ros/) by [Nima](https://answers.ros.org/users/5442/nima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-07-17**:
0.02mm?! Is that a typo or are you looking at industrial robots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may want to take a look at the hardware supported by ros-industrial: http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/supported_hardware

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1